# Tuning the data class for the SysLat System Latency Testing hardware for gaming computers - SysLat Cleanup #1

Tags: c++, embedded

Here's my open source project for testing the latency of gaming computers : https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software

This software controls the hardware that tests the latency of a gaming computer that can be found at https://syslat.com/. The follow up question to this question can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256063/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-2?noredirect=1&lq=1). Since this program is too large to include in a single question here are related questions [Cleaning up the USB controller](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256149/cleaning-up-usb-implementation-use-syslat-cleanup-3) and [Cleaning up the Main Dialog](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256151/cleaning-up-static-member-variable-declaration-and-definition).

Today I'd like to attempt to clean up my "SysLatData" class.

Header file here:        https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLatData.h
Implementation here:     https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLatData.cpp
Definition and use here: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp

I think the first couple things I need to attack (after a cleanup of typedef and my include guards) are:

- Moving some functionality out of this class and into the core program (specifically `UpdateSLD()`) and creating setters.
- Moving the export functions into a new static, generic library (specifically `CreateJSONSLD()` and `ExportData()`)
- Moving the unrelated variables into the core program.(such as `m_targetApp`, `m_RTSSVersion`, and `m_boxAnchor`)

But I don't truly know what to do and that's why I'm here!

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SYSLATDATA_H
#define SYSLATDATA_H

//#define MAX_TESTS                                     500
#define MOVING_AVERAGE                                  100
#define EVR_MIN                                         3
#define EVR_MAX                                         100

//putting all of this in a struct has got to be unbelievably stupid
typedef struct SYSLAT_DATA {
    vector<int>         m_allResults;
    vector<string>      m_v_strRTSSWindow;
    vector<string>      m_v_strActiveWindow;
    int                 m_counter = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyTotal = 0;
    double              m_systemLatencyAverage = 0;
    int                 m_counterEVR = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyTotalEVR = 0; //EVR stands for expected value range
    double              m_systemLatencyAverageEVR = 0;
    int                 m_a_MovingAverage[MOVING_AVERAGE] = { 0 };//if I end up using a "total tests" var, then this should probably just be split into 2 pointers pointing at the "head" of the totalTests var and head-100 or something...
    int                 m_systemLatencyMedian = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyMedianEVR = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyMax = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyMin = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyMaxEVR = 0;
    int                 m_systemLatencyMinEVR = 0;
}SYSLAT_DATA;

class CSysLatData
{
protected: 
    SYSLAT_DATA         sld;
    CString             m_strSysLatResultsComplete;
    HANDLE              m_Mutex = NULL;
    CString             m_strError;
    time_t              m_startTime, m_endTime;
    char                m_startDate[26], m_endDate[26];

public:
    CSysLatData(); //this constructor only opens a mutex... does the destructor need to close the mutex? Also, do I need to init the struct in the constructor? It should init to all 0's off the bat...
    
    Json::Value         jsonSLD; //this is basically a second copy of the data... will probably eat up a BOATLOAD of memory for no reason. There's got to be a better way...
    
    //using getters and setters for all of these seems stupid...
    int                 GetCounter();
    int                 GetTotal();
    double              GetAverage();
    int                 GetCounterEVR();
    int                 GetTotalEVR();
    double              GetAverageEVR();
    CString             GetStringResult();

    int                 GetMedian();
    int                 GetMedianEVR();
    int                 GetMax();
    int                 GetMin();
    int                 GetMaxEVR();
    int                 GetMinEVR();
    //int*              GetMovingAverage(); //????

    string              m_targetApp = "Unknown";
    string              m_RTSSVersion = "0.0.0";
    string              m_boxAnchor = "Unknown";
    struct tm*          startTimeUTC;
    double              m_testDuration;

    //double            CalculateMovingAverage(); //this function would be for calculating it from scratch...
    //double            UpdateMovingAverage(); //this function would be used if I'm updating the moving average every time I get a new value
    void                SetEndTime();
    
    void                UpdateSLD(unsigned int loopCounter, const CString& sysLatResults, string RTSSWindow, string activeWindow, DWORD fgPID, DWORD rtssPID);
    
    //mutex functions
    void                CheckSLDMutex();
    BOOL                AcquireSLDMutex();
    void                ReleaseSLDMutex();
    void                CloseSLDMutex();

    void                AppendError(const CString& error);

    // I think I need to make the following 2 functions return BOOLs or INTs based on whether or not they failed.
    void                CreateJSONSLD();
    void                ExportData(int testNumber, string path = ".\\SysLat_Logs", int totalLogs = 10000);

    bool                dataExported = false;
    bool                dataUploaded = false;
};
#endif
```

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you already know what can be improved here.  You should probably do that first, before asking for a review.

Comment: Well, I've included my best guess, but I'm hesitant to attempt to implement it without seeking some kind of review or head nod from... anyone. I guess I can take your comment as that head nod.

Comment: @TobySpeight is correct it seems like you know what needs to be done. We can't offer advice on what needs to be done, we can only make observations about working code that is already complete. We also need `all of` the code you want reviewed in the question, we can only use linked code repositories as references. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). One of your options is to break the large class into smaller classes and include those smaller classes in the larger class. [SOLID programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Comment: Don't interpret my comment as a review - just stating that the code should be *finished* to the best of your ability before it's ready for review.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: Thanks @pacmaninbw. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid macros

You should declare constants as `constexpr` variables instead of as `#define`s, like so:

```
constexpr std::size_t MOVING_AVERAGE = 100;
```

## Use `std::size_t` for sizes, counts and array indices

An `int` might not be large enough to represent all possible sizes of arrays, and negative values don't make sense for sizes and counts either. The proper type is [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

If you are not dealing with arrays or loop counters, but just need a variable to count events, you might also use `std::size_t` for that instead of `int`, although it might be better to think about how large the number of events might be, and use an [integer type with an explicit size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

## Use `double` consistently for latency measurements

I recommend you use `double` for all variables that store latencies, whether it's just a single measurement or an average. You clearly involve `double`s at some point, and while there might be some overhead of using `double`s everywhere, you get rid of the overhead of converting between `int` and `double`.

## Be consistent when naming variables

You seem to be using [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for only a few of the variables, like `m_v_strRTSWindow` and `m_strSysLatResultsComplete`, but many of the other variables do not have their types encoded in the name. If you are not doing this consistently, there is no point in using Hungarian notation, and I strongly recommend you stop using it everywhere.

Furhtermore, you use the `m_` prefix for member variables almost everywhere, but some variables don't have it, like `sld`, `jsonSLD`, `startTimeUTC`, `dataExported` and `dataUploaded`.

## There is no need to `typedef struct`s in C++

Instead of writing:

```
typedef struct SYSLAT_DATA {
    ...
} SYSLAT_DATA:
```

You can just write:

```
struct SYSLAT_DATA {
    ...
};
```

Unlike C, in C++ you can then just use the type `SYSLAT_DATA` without having to write `struct` in front of it.

## Avoid repeating names

In `struct SYSLAT_DATA`, there are many member variables that are named `m_systemLatencySomething`. Since the `struct` itself already mentions system latency, you don't have to repeat it. This shortens the variable names considerably.

## Use `std::chrono` types for anything time related

I see you use various C types for storing time, including `time_t` and `struct tm`, and you even have some `char` arrays to hold dates. Since C++11, there are the excellent [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) facilities of dealing with timepoints and durations. I strongly recommend you start using those consistently.

## Use `std::mutex` instead of platform-specific functions

Since C++11, [threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), [mutexes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [other synchronisation primitives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) have become standardized. I recommend you use the standard functions instead of Windows-specific ones. The types and functions from the STL are much more natural to use in a C++ program, and it will make it easier if you ever want to port your project to other operating systems.

For example, if you use a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for `m_Mutex`, you don't need a constructor and destructor in `class CSysLatData` anymore.

## Who is responsible for locking the mutex?

I see you have member functions like `AcquireSLDMutex()` and `ReleaseSLDMutex()`. This strongly hints that `class CSysLatData` itself doesn't lock or release the mutex, but requires other parts of your program to do this. In that case, it is probably more logical to move the mutex out of `class CSysLatData`, so the `class` is completely thread-agnostic.

## Keep your `struct`s and `class`es lean

> `//putting all of this in a struct has got to be unbelievably stupid`

Probably. What are all these variables for? Do they really need to be all stored? You should only keep those variables that store data that you need later on. Temporary variables used just inside one function most likely do not need to go into a `struct`,
and unless there is a performance reason for doing so, you don't need to store anything that can be derived from other variables.

## Getters and setters

> `//using getters and setters for all of these seems stupid...`

Getters and setters have their place, but indeed having to write tens of getters seems silly. In your case, you can replace most getters with a single one that looks like this:

```
const SYSLAT_DATA &GetData() {
    return sld;
}
```

This returns a `const` reference to `sld`. The compiler will enforce that the caller cannot write to `sld`, only read from it. So instead of the caller writing:

```
CSysLatData syslat;
...
std::size_t counter = syslat.GetCounter();
double total = syslat.GetTotal();
...
```

It can now write:

```
CSysLatData syslat;
...
auto &data = syslat.GetData();
std::size_t counter = data.m_counter;
double total = data.m_total;
...
```

## Duplication of variables in `struct SYSLAT_DATA`

Apart from the vectors at the start, there seem to be two copies of each variable, one named `m_something`, and one named `m_somethingEVR`. Maybe it makes sense to rewrite it to something like:

```
struct SYSLAT_DATA {
    struct Statistics {
         std::size_t counter;
         double total;
         double average;
         double median;
         ...
    };

    std::vector<...> ...;
    ...

    Statistics m_statistics;
    Statistics m_statisticsEVR;
};
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for all of this. I'm going to look through and try to implement most of these and I'll report back.

Comment: Regarding the int vs. double issue... the hardware is currently only able to accurately measure and send values in milliseconds, so until I do operations on multiple measurements I don't need double. Also, I had some speed inconsistency issues with a few operations that I was doing that caused my USB read times to increase when using doubles, so I'm hesitant to move back towards them.

Comment: I was able to implement basically all of your suggestions. Thank you. https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/commit/662237af6d1529b94015a5ed9e68f72c6c4719b7

Comment: I'd toss you an upvote, but I don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: @Skewjo you have enough points to up vote.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @pacmaninbw.