# Turning a data class with too much functionality into a POD - SysLat Cleanup #2

Tags: c++, embedded

This is a follow up question to [Tuning the data class for the SysLat System Latency Testing hardware for gaming computers - SysLat Cleanup #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256046/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-1).

Since the program is too large and complex to put into one question I have also posted a question about the [USB controller](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256149/cleaning-up-usb-implementation-use-syslat-cleanup-3) and the [dialog that controls the entire program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256151/cleaning-up-static-member-variable-declaration-and-definition).

Here's my open source project: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software

Today I'm attempting to clean up my "SysLatData" class, and the effort has [gone very well so far](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256046/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-1/256052#256052), and I'm looking to pretty well finalize it now if possible.

Header file here: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLatData.h
Implementation here: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLatData.cpp
Definition and use here: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp

```
#pragma once

//Without the following 2 macros the date library spits out 50+ errors about min and max being undefined.
#undef max 
#undef min
#include <date/date.h> //Should likely move this to StdAfx.h, but I'm not sure if I can because of the macro issue.
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr size_t MOVING_AVERAGE = 100;
constexpr size_t EVR_MIN = 3;
constexpr size_t EVR_MAX = 100;

struct SYSLAT_DATA {
    struct Statistics {
        std::size_t counter = 0;
        int total = 0;
        double average = 0.0;
        int median = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        double approxMovingAvg = 0.0;
    };

    vector<int>         m_allResults;
    vector<string>      m_v_strRTSSWindow;
    vector<string>      m_v_strActiveWindow;
    
    Statistics          m_statistics;
    Statistics          m_statisticsEVR;
};

class CSysLatData
{
protected: 
    SYSLAT_DATA         m_sld;
    Json::Value         m_JSONsld; //this is basically a second copy of the data... will probably eat up a BOATLOAD of memory for no reason. There's got to be a better way...
    int                 systemLatency = 0;

    std::mutex          m_Mutex;
    string              m_strError = "";

    const system_clock::time_point  m_startTime = system_clock::now();
    system_clock::time_point        m_endTime;
    duration<int>                   m_testDuration; 

public:
    const SYSLAT_DATA&  GetData() {return m_sld;}
    const Json::Value&  GetJSONData() { return m_JSONsld; }
    const int&          GetSystemLatency() { return systemLatency; }

    double              CalculateMovingAverage(double currentAvg, int input);
    void                SetEndTime();
    void                UpdateSLD(unsigned int loopCounter, const string& sysLatResults, string RTSSWindow, string activeWindow, DWORD fgPID, DWORD rtssPID);
    void                AppendError(const string& error);
    
    void                CreateJSONSLD(); // I think I may need to make this and the following functions return bools or ints based on whether or not they failed.
    void                ExportData(int testNumber, string path = ".\\SysLat_Logs", int totalLogs = 10000);

    string              m_RTSSVersion = "0.0.0";
    string              m_targetApp = "Unknown";
    string              m_boxAnchor = "Unknown";

    bool                m_bDataExported = false;
    bool                m_bDataUploaded = false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Make export data a static method, pass in the object to be exported.
- Do not have a member variable just to store JSON data; generate the JSON only as part of the export method.

Comment: Good ideas. I thought that I had fabricated a reason to store JSON... but I certainly can't remember it now.