# USB implementation of device that tests system latency on gaming computers - SysLat Cleanup #3

Tags: c++, windows, embedded

Here's my open source project: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software.
The hardware controlled by this software can be found at https://syslat.com/. This is the 3rd question in a series of questions to get the code production ready. The other questions are [Tuning the data class 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256046/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-1) [the follow up to the tuning the data class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256063/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-2) and the [dialog that controls the whole program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256151/cleaning-up-static-member-variable-declaration-and-definition).

Today I'd like to attempt to clean up my USB implementation.

Header file here:        https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/USBController.h
Implementation here:     https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/USBController.cpp
Definition and use here: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp

[USBController.h](https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/USBController.h)

```
#pragma once
#ifndef USBCONTROLLER_H
#define USBCONTROLLER_H



struct SSerInfo {
    SSerInfo() : bUsbDevice(FALSE) {}
    CString strDevPath;          // Device path for use with CreateFile()
    CString strPortName;         // Simple name (i.e. COM1)
    CString strFriendlyName;     // Full name to be displayed to a user
    BOOL bUsbDevice;             // Provided through a USB connection?
    CString strPortDesc;         // friendly name without the COMx
};


class CUSBController
{
    /*
protected:
    
    //These vars aren't actually in use anywhere yet...
    const CString& PortSpecifier;
    DWORD BaudRate = CBR_9600; //9600 Baud
    /*other Baud options:
    CBR_110             110
    CBR_300             300
    CBR_600             600
    CBR_1200            1200
    CBR_2400            2400
    CBR_4800            4800
    CBR_9600            9600
    CBR_14400           14400
    CBR_19200           19200
    CBR_38400           38400
    CBR_56000           56000
    CBR_57600           57600
    CBR_115200          115200
    CBR_128000          128000
    CBR_256000          256000
    
    BYTE ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits
    BYTE Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity
    BYTE StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop
    */
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Helpers for enumerating the available serial ports.
    // These throw a CString on failure, describing the nature of
    // the error that occurred.

    void                EnumPortsWdm(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi);
    void                EnumPortsWNt4(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi);
    void                EnumPortsW9x(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi);
    void                SearchPnpKeyW9x(HKEY hkPnp, BOOL bUsbDevice, CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi);

public:
    
    HANDLE              OpenComPort(const CString& PortSpecifier);
    void                CloseComPort(HANDLE hPort);
    bool                IsComPortOpened(HANDLE hPort);
    int                 ReadByte(HANDLE port);

    //1-6-21
    //This only half works on my system, so I also have to use "_WINBASE_::GetCommPorts()", but it does give me the "friendly name", which is what I really need.
    void                EnumSerialPorts(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi, BOOL bIgnoreBusyPorts);
    
    
};
#endif
```

[USBController.cpp](https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/USBController.cpp)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "USBController.h"
//#include <objbase.h>
//#include <initguid.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <ntddser.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Setupapi.lib")

HANDLE CUSBController::OpenComPort(const CString& PortSpecifier)
{
    HANDLE hPort = CreateFile(PortSpecifier, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PurgeComm(hPort, PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    DCB dcb = { 0 };
    if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
    {
        CloseHandle(hPort);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    if (!SetCommState(hPort, &dcb))
    {
        CloseHandle(hPort);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR); //receive character event

    // Read this carefully because timeouts are important
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-commtimeouts
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };

    return hPort;
}
void CUSBController::CloseComPort(HANDLE hPort)
{
    PurgeComm(hPort, PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    CloseHandle(hPort);
}
bool CUSBController::IsComPortOpened(HANDLE hPort)
{
    return hPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
int CUSBController::ReadByte(HANDLE hPort)
{
    int retVal;

    BYTE Byte;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
    if (FALSE == ReadFile(hPort, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0)) //read 1
        retVal = 0x101;
    retVal = Byte;

    return retVal;
}

/*************************************************************************
* Serial port enumeration routines
*
* The EnumSerialPort function will populate an array of SSerInfo structs,
* each of which contains information about one serial port present in
* the system. Note that this code must be linked with setupapi.lib,
* which is included with the Win32 SDK.
*
* by Zach Gorman <gormanjz@hotmail.com>
*
* Copyright (c) 2002 Archetype Auction Software, Inc. All rights reserved.
*
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
* modification, are permitted provided that the following condition is
* met: Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
* notice, this condition and the following disclaimer.
*
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED
* WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
* OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
* DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL ARCHETYPE AUCTION SOFTWARE OR ITS
* AFFILIATES BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
* EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
* PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
* PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
* NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
* SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
************************************************************************/

// The following define is from ntddser.h in the DDK. It is also
// needed for serial port enumeration.
/*#ifndef GUID_CLASS_COMPORT
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_CLASS_COMPORT, 0x86e0d1e0L, 0x8089, 0x11d0, 0x9c, 0xe4, \
    0x08, 0x00, 0x3e, 0x30, 0x1f, 0x73);
#endif*/


//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Routine for enumerating the available serial ports.
// Throws a CString on failure, describing the error that
// occurred. If bIgnoreBusyPorts is TRUE, ports that can't
// be opened for read/write access are not included.
void  CUSBController::EnumSerialPorts(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi, BOOL bIgnoreBusyPorts)
{
    // Clear the output array
    asi.RemoveAll();

    // Use different techniques to enumerate the available serial
    // ports, depending on the OS we're using
    OSVERSIONINFO vi;
    vi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(vi);
    if (!::GetVersionEx(&vi)) {
        CString str;
        str.Format("Could not get OS version. (err=%lx)",
            GetLastError());
        throw str;
    }
    // Handle windows 9x and NT4 specially
    if (vi.dwMajorVersion < 5) {
        if (vi.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
            EnumPortsWNt4(asi);
        else
            EnumPortsW9x(asi);
    }
    else {
        // Win2k and later support a standard API for
        // enumerating hardware devices.
        EnumPortsWdm(asi);
    }

    for (int ii = 0; ii < asi.GetSize(); ii++)
    {
        SSerInfo& rsi = asi[ii];
        if (bIgnoreBusyPorts) {
            // Only display ports that can be opened for read/write
            HANDLE hCom = CreateFile(rsi.strDevPath,
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,    /* comm devices must be opened w/exclusive-access */
                NULL, /* no security attrs */
                OPEN_EXISTING, /* comm devices must use OPEN_EXISTING */
                0,    /* not overlapped I/O */
                NULL  /* hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices */
            );
            if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                // It can't be opened; remove it.
                asi.RemoveAt(ii);
                ii--;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                // It can be opened! Close it and add it to the list
                ::CloseHandle(hCom);
            }
        }

        // Come up with a name for the device.
        // If there is no friendly name, use the port name.
        if (rsi.strFriendlyName.IsEmpty())
            rsi.strFriendlyName = rsi.strPortName;

        // If there is no description, try to make one up from
        // the friendly name.
        if (rsi.strPortDesc.IsEmpty()) {
            // If the port name is of the form "ACME Port (COM3)"
            // then strip off the " (COM3)"
            rsi.strPortDesc = rsi.strFriendlyName;
            int startdex = rsi.strPortDesc.Find(" (");
            int enddex = rsi.strPortDesc.Find(")");
            if (startdex > 0 && enddex ==
                (rsi.strPortDesc.GetLength() - 1))
                rsi.strPortDesc = rsi.strPortDesc.Left(startdex);
        }
    }
}

// Helpers for EnumSerialPorts
void CUSBController::EnumPortsWdm(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi)
{
    CString strErr;
    // Create a device information set that will be the container for 
    // the device interfaces.
    GUID* guidDev = (GUID*)&GUID_CLASS_COMPORT;

    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA* pDetData = NULL;

    try {
        hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(guidDev,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
        );

        if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            strErr.Format("SetupDiGetClassDevs failed. (err=%lx)",
                GetLastError());
            throw strErr;
        }

        // Enumerate the serial ports
        BOOL bOk = TRUE;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ifcData;
        DWORD dwDetDataSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) + 256;
        pDetData = (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA*) new char[dwDetDataSize];
        // This is required, according to the documentation. Yes,
        // it's weird.
        ifcData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        pDetData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

        for (DWORD ii = 0; bOk; ii++) {
            bOk = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, guidDev, ii, &ifcData);
            if (bOk) {
                // Got a device. Get the details.
                SP_DEVINFO_DATA devdata = { sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA) };
                bOk = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &ifcData, pDetData, dwDetDataSize, NULL, &devdata);
                if (bOk) {
                    CString strDevPath(pDetData->DevicePath);
                    // Got a path to the device. Try to get some more info.
                    CHAR fname[256];
                    CHAR desc[256];
                    BOOL bSuccess = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devdata, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, NULL, (PBYTE)fname, sizeof(fname), NULL);
                    bSuccess = bSuccess && SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devdata, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, NULL, (PBYTE)desc, sizeof(desc), NULL);
                    BOOL bUsbDevice = FALSE;
                    CHAR locinfo[256];
                    if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devdata, SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION, NULL, (PBYTE)locinfo, sizeof(locinfo), NULL))
                    {
                        // Just check the first three characters to determine
                        // if the port is connected to the USB bus. This isn't
                        // an infallible method; it would be better to use the
                        // BUS GUID. Currently, Windows doesn't let you query
                        // that though (SPDRP_BUSTYPEGUID seems to exist in
                        // documentation only).
                        bUsbDevice = (strncmp(locinfo, "USB", 3) == 0);
                    }
                    if (bSuccess) {
                        // Add an entry to the array
                        SSerInfo si;
                        si.strDevPath = strDevPath;
                        si.strFriendlyName = fname;
                        si.strPortDesc = desc;
                        si.bUsbDevice = bUsbDevice;
                        asi.Add(si);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    strErr.Format("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail failed. (err=%lx)",
                        GetLastError());
                    throw strErr;
                }
            }
            else {
                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                if (err != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) {
                    strErr.Format("SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces failed. (err=%lx)", err);
                    throw strErr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (CString strCatchErr) {
        strErr = strCatchErr;
    }

    if (pDetData != NULL)
        delete[](char*)pDetData;
    if (hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);

    if (!strErr.IsEmpty())
        throw strErr;
}
void CUSBController::EnumPortsWNt4(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi)
{
    // NT4's driver model is totally different, and not that
    // many people use NT4 anymore. Just try all the COM ports
    // between 1 and 16
    SSerInfo si;
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 16; ii++) {
        CString strPort;
        strPort.Format("COM%d", ii);
        si.strDevPath = CString("\\\\.\\") + strPort;
        si.strPortName = strPort;
        asi.Add(si);
    }
}
void CUSBController::EnumPortsW9x(CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi)
{
    // Look at all keys in HKLM\Enum, searching for subkeys named
    // *PNP0500 and *PNP0501. Within these subkeys, search for
    // sub-subkeys containing value entries with the name "PORTNAME"
    // Search all subkeys of HKLM\Enum\USBPORTS for PORTNAME entries.

    // First, open HKLM\Enum
    HKEY hkEnum = NULL;
    HKEY hkSubEnum = NULL;
    HKEY hkSubSubEnum = NULL;

    try {
        if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Enum", 0, KEY_READ,
            &hkEnum) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw CString("Could not read from HKLM\\Enum");

        // Enumerate the subkeys of HKLM\Enum
        char acSubEnum[128];
        DWORD dwSubEnumIndex = 0;
        DWORD dwSize = sizeof(acSubEnum);
        while (RegEnumKeyEx(hkEnum, dwSubEnumIndex++, acSubEnum, &dwSize,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            HKEY hkSubEnum = NULL;
            if (RegOpenKeyEx(hkEnum, acSubEnum, 0, KEY_READ,
                &hkSubEnum) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw CString("Could not read from HKLM\\Enum\\") + acSubEnum;

            // Enumerate the subkeys of HKLM\Enum\*\, looking for keys
            // named *PNP0500 and *PNP0501 (or anything in USBPORTS)
            BOOL bUsbDevice = (strcmp(acSubEnum, "USBPORTS") == 0);
            char acSubSubEnum[128];
            dwSize = sizeof(acSubSubEnum);  // set the buffer size
            DWORD dwSubSubEnumIndex = 0;
            while (RegEnumKeyEx(hkSubEnum, dwSubSubEnumIndex++, acSubSubEnum,
                &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                BOOL bMatch = (strcmp(acSubSubEnum, "*PNP0500") == 0 ||
                    strcmp(acSubSubEnum, "*PNP0501") == 0 ||
                    bUsbDevice);
                if (bMatch) {
                    HKEY hkSubSubEnum = NULL;
                    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hkSubEnum, acSubSubEnum, 0, KEY_READ,
                        &hkSubSubEnum) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                        throw CString("Could not read from HKLM\\Enum\\") +
                        acSubEnum + "\\" + acSubSubEnum;
                    SearchPnpKeyW9x(hkSubSubEnum, bUsbDevice, asi);
                    RegCloseKey(hkSubSubEnum);
                    hkSubSubEnum = NULL;
                }

                dwSize = sizeof(acSubSubEnum);  // restore the buffer size
            }

            RegCloseKey(hkSubEnum);
            hkSubEnum = NULL;
            dwSize = sizeof(acSubEnum); // restore the buffer size
        }
    }
    catch (CString strError) {
        if (hkEnum != NULL)
            RegCloseKey(hkEnum);
        if (hkSubEnum != NULL)
            RegCloseKey(hkSubEnum);
        if (hkSubSubEnum != NULL)
            RegCloseKey(hkSubSubEnum);
        throw strError;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hkEnum);
}
void CUSBController::SearchPnpKeyW9x(HKEY hkPnp, BOOL bUsbDevice, CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&>& asi)
{
    // Enumerate the subkeys of the given PNP key, looking for values with
    // the name "PORTNAME"
    // First, open HKLM\Enum
    HKEY hkSubPnp = NULL;

    try {
        // Enumerate the subkeys of HKLM\Enum\*\PNP050[01]
        char acSubPnp[128];
        DWORD dwSubPnpIndex = 0;
        DWORD dwSize = sizeof(acSubPnp);
        while (RegEnumKeyEx(hkPnp, dwSubPnpIndex++, acSubPnp, &dwSize,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            HKEY hkSubPnp = NULL;
            if (RegOpenKeyEx(hkPnp, acSubPnp, 0, KEY_READ,
                &hkSubPnp) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                throw CString("Could not read from HKLM\\Enum\\...\\")
                + acSubPnp;

            // Look for the PORTNAME value
            char acValue[128];
            dwSize = sizeof(acValue);
            if (RegQueryValueEx(hkSubPnp, "PORTNAME", NULL, NULL, (BYTE*)acValue,
                &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                CString strPortName(acValue);

                // Got the portname value. Look for a friendly name.
                CString strFriendlyName;
                dwSize = sizeof(acValue);
                if (RegQueryValueEx(hkSubPnp, "FRIENDLYNAME", NULL, NULL, (BYTE*)acValue,
                    &dwSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    strFriendlyName = acValue;

                // Prepare an entry for the output array.
                SSerInfo si;
                si.strDevPath = CString("\\\\.\\") + strPortName;
                si.strPortName = strPortName;
                si.strFriendlyName = strFriendlyName;
                si.bUsbDevice = bUsbDevice;

                // Overwrite duplicates.
                BOOL bDup = FALSE;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < asi.GetSize() && !bDup; ii++)
                {
                    if (asi[ii].strPortName == strPortName) {
                        bDup = TRUE;
                        asi[ii] = si;
                    }
                }
                if (!bDup) {
                    // Add an entry to the array
                    asi.Add(si);
                }
            }

            RegCloseKey(hkSubPnp);
            hkSubPnp = NULL;
            dwSize = sizeof(acSubPnp);  // restore the buffer size
        }
    }
    catch (CString strError) {
        if (hkSubPnp != NULL)
            RegCloseKey(hkSubPnp);
        throw strError;
    }
}
```

And finally, here's one of the functions in [SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp](https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp), that I believe is causing me issues, where the class is used:

```
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_DynamicComPortMenu()
{
    CMenu* MainMenu = GetMenu();
    CMenu* SettingsMenu = MainMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
    CMenu* ComPortMenu = SettingsMenu->GetSubMenu(0);

    if (ComPortMenu)
    {
        BOOL appended = false;
        BOOL deleted = false;
        m_COMPortCount = 0;
        
        for(auto i = 0; i < m_COMPortInfo.GetSize(); i++) {
            ComPortMenu->DeleteMenu(ID_COMPORT_START + m_COMPortCount, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            if (m_COMPortCount < ID_COMPORT_END - ID_COMPORT_START) {
                string usb_info = m_COMPortInfo[i].strFriendlyName;
                DEBUG_PRINT("Friendly Name: " + usb_info)

                appended = ComPortMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_COMPORT_START + m_COMPortCount, m_COMPortInfo[i].strFriendlyName);
                string menuString = m_COMPortInfo[i].strFriendlyName;
                size_t pos = menuString.rfind("(");
                menuString.replace(0, pos + 1, "");
                pos = menuString.rfind(")");
                menuString.replace(pos, menuString.size(), "");

                if (strcmp(menuString.c_str(), SysLatOpt.m_PortSpecifier.c_str()) == 0) {
                    MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_COMPORT_START + m_COMPortCount, MF_CHECKED);
                }

                m_COMPortCount++;
            }
            else { //catch or throw errors here maybe?
                break;
            }
        }
        deleted = ComPortMenu->DeleteMenu(ID_USBPORT_PLACEHOLDER, MF_BYCOMMAND);

        DEBUG_PRINT(("String appended: " + to_string(appended)).c_str())
        DEBUG_PRINT(("Placeholder deleted: " + to_string(deleted)).c_str())

    }
    DrawMenuBar();

}
```

Comment: You may want to check out https://libusb.info/ for a portable USB library that runs on Windows, Linux and MacOS.