# Dialog that controls external USB device that tests the latency of gaming computers - SysLat Cleanup #4

Tags: c++, windows, embedded

I have several static variables in my dialog class that I'm declaring in the header and then defining immediately in the cpp file. They are being used in an application with 2 threads, and these particular variables are mostly shared between both threads.

This is the fourth question in an effort to get the program ready for production. The other cleanup questions are [SysLat Cleanup #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256046/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-1), [SysLat Cleanup #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256063/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-2) and [SysLat Cleanup #3 (USB control)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256149/cleaning-up-usb-implementation-use-syslat-cleanup-3). The hardware is available at https://syslat.com/.

1. Main thread that runs the dialog box and manages various connections (data objects, menus, a USB device connection, and a shared memory connection)
2. A "high priority" thread that reads USB input, runs shared memory commands, and updates one of the core data objects (a `CSysLatData` object).

This code is currently working with no issues, but it feels to me that it is unsafe, incorrect, or in a poor location.

Here's the header file:

```
// SysLat_SoftwareDlg.h : header file
//
// created by Unwinder
// modified by Skewjo
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef _SYSLAT_SOFTWAREDLG_H_INCLUDED_
#define _SYSLAT_SOFTWAREDLG_H_INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#include "RTSSSharedMemory.h"
#include "RTSSClient.h"
#include "SysLatData.h"
#include "HardwareID.h"
#include "MachineInfo.h"
#include "USBController.h"

class CSysLat_SoftwareDlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    CSysLat_SoftwareDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor
    ~CSysLat_SoftwareDlg();
// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg)
    enum { IDD = IDD_SYSLAT_SOFTWARE_DIALOG };
    //}}AFX_DATA

    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg)
    public:
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:
    BOOL                            PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
    void                            Refresh();
    void                            R_GetRTSSConfigs();
    BOOL                            R_SysLatStats();
    void                            R_Position();
    void                            R_ProcessNames();
    void                            R_StrOSD();
    void                            R_DynamicComPortMenu();
    void                            R_DynamicAppMenu();
    static void                     AppendError(const CString& error); //this function is duplicated between this class and SysLatData - need to make this not used by the thread and then I can make it non-static like the other refresh functions

    //Drawing thread functions
    static unsigned int __stdcall   CreateDrawingThread(void* data);
    static void                     DrawSquare(CRTSSClient sysLatClient, CString& colorString);
    static string                   GetProcessNameFromPID(DWORD processID);
    static string                   GetActiveWindowTitle();
    static void                     ProcessNameTrim(string&, string&);

    //Dialog menu related functions
    //Tools
    void                            ReInitThread();//used by the "New Test" menu function
    void                            ExportData();
    void                            UploadData();

    //Settings
    void                            DebugMode();
    void                            TestUploadMode();
    void                            DisplaySysLatInOSD();
    void                            OpenPreferences();
    void                            OpenTestCtrl();
    void                            ExportData(Json::Value stuffToExport);
    void                            OnComPortChanged(UINT nID);
    void                            OnTargetWindowChanged(UINT nID);
    void                            CheckUpdate();
    void                            SetSURegValue(string regValue);

    //Members
    HardwareID                  m_hardwareID;
    MachineInfo                 m_machineInfo;
    CRTSSClient                 m_SysLatStatsClient; //This RTSS client is "owned" by the dialog box and the "drawing thread" function "owns" the other
    CArray<SSerInfo, SSerInfo&> m_COMPortInfo;

    HANDLE                      m_drawingThreadHandle;
    int                         m_COMPortCount;
    static std::shared_ptr<CSysLatData> m_pOperatingSLD;
    //static CSysLatData*           m_pOperatingSLD;
    //vector<CSysLatData*>      m_vpPreviousSLD;
    vector<std::shared_ptr<CSysLatData>> m_vpPreviousSLD;
    static constexpr const char* m_caSysLat = "SysLat";
    static constexpr const char* m_caSysLatStats = "SysLatStats";
    static DWORD                m_sysLatOwnedSlot;//UGH - I'm specifcally making the sysLatClient object thread local... but then to get a value from it I need to make a static var in this class to track it.  Seems dumb.
    static CString              m_updateString;
    static CString              m_strError;
    static CString              m_strBlack;
    static CString              m_strWhite;
    static DWORD                m_AppArraySize;

    time_t                      m_elapsedTimeStart, m_elapsedTimeEnd;

    //the names and uses of the following 3 vars is stupid... Need to fix it
    unsigned int                myCounter = 0;
    static unsigned int         m_loopSize; //really need to change the name of this var to "threadContinue" or something more descriptive
    static unsigned int         m_LoopCounterRefresh;
    
    //Debug Options
    BOOL                        m_bDebugMode = false; //save to config
    BOOL                        m_bTestUploadMode = false; //change name?
    BOOL                        m_bSysLatInOSD = false;

    //RTSS Configs - can't these be moved??
    DWORD                       m_dwSharedMemoryVersion;
    DWORD                       m_dwMaxTextSize;
    BOOL                        m_bFormatTagsSupported;
    BOOL                        m_bObjTagsSupported;
    BOOL                        m_bRTSSInitConfig = false;
    
    //previously existing members
    BOOL                        m_bMultiLineOutput;
    BOOL                        m_bFormatTags;
    BOOL                        m_bFillGraphs;
    BOOL                        m_bConnected;

    HICON                       m_hIcon;
    UINT                        m_nTimerID;

    CFont                       m_font;
    CRichEditCtrl               m_richEditCtrl;

    static CString              m_strStatus;
    CString                     m_strInstallPath;

    //for dark mode
    COLORREF                    m_color;
    CBrush                      m_brush;
    CRect                       m_clientRect;


    CHAR                        pathToSysLat[MAX_PATH];
    

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg)
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent);
    afx_msg void OnDestroy();
    afx_msg LRESULT OnSTMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
};


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And here's the cpp file:

```
// SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp : implementation file
//
// created by Unwinder
// modified by Skewjo
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SysLat_Software.h"
#include "SysLat_SoftwareDlg.h"
#include "USBController.h"
#include "HTTP_Client_Async.h"
#include "HTTP_Client_Async_SSL.h"
#include "SysLatPreferences.h"
#include "AboutDlg.h"
#include "PreferencesDlg.h"
#include "TestCtrl.h" //this one should probably have a suffix of "dlg"...
#include "version.h"

//probably need to move the following 2 includes to stdafx.h
#include <memory> 
#include <shellapi.h>

//TODO:
// Transfer TODO to GitHub Issues...
// DONE - Organize TODO...
//      DONE - Core Functionality
//      DONE - Menu
//      DONE - Data Issues
//      DONE - Optimization
//      DONE - Organizational Issues
//      DONE - Anti-Fraud
//
//
//Issues completed before the TODO reorg:
//  NOT AVAILABLE(?) - Profile Setting - Set "Refresh Period" to 0 milliseconds  - doesn't appear to be an option available via shared memory
//  DONE - Profile Setting - Change default corner to bottom right
//  DONE (opacity) - Profile Setting - Change "text"(foreground) color to white (255, 255, 255) with an opacity of 100
//  DONE - Profile Setting - Change color of "background"(?) to black (0, 0, 0) with an opacity of 100
//      DONE - Better yet - if I could change the box to use a plain black and plain white box so any other text isn't screwed up, that would be better
//  DONE - Profile Setting - Set box size to what I want it to be?
//  DONE - Change class/namespace name of RTSSSharedMemorySampleDlg to SysLatDlg
//  DONE - Change class/namespace of RTSSSharedMemorySample to SysLat
//  DONE - Add minimize button
//  DONE(well... it half-ass works) - Make System Latency appear in OSD
//  DONE - Save results to a table - using an array
//  DONE - Determine active window vs window that RTSS is operating in?
//  DONE(mostly) - Launch RTSS automatically in the background if it's not running
//  DONE - Add hotkey to restart readings (F11?)
//  DONE - Seperate some initialization that happens in "Refresh" function into a different "Refresh-like" function?? - partially done?
//  DONE - Re-org this file into 3-4 new classes - Dialog related functions, RTSS related, DrawingThread related, and USB related
//  DONE - BUT THERE ARE PROBLEMS(it just changed the priority of which client(syslat vs syslatStats) - Make the program statically linked so that it all packages together nicely in a single DLL
//  DONE(BUT NOT GREAT) - Dynamically build the "drawSquare" string and change the P tag to account for the current corner and all other OSD text?
//      DONE(Mostly...new issue created) - Then create an option to disable that setting - add keyboard arrow functionality to move it into place manually.
//
//
//
//
//Core Functionality:
//  DONE - Add HTTP post function for uploading logs to website - use boost.beast library?
//  Some errors currently appear very briefly and are overwritten when the refresh function runs - Clean up the refresh function, then come up with new error scheme.
//      Either use error codes, or check all errors  again in the refresh function(that doesn't make sense though, right?)... or maybe do dialog error pop-ups when errors occur outside of "refresh"?
//  Move ExportData function out of SysLatData? Or just use it to retrieve a jsoncpp object & combine it with other jsoncpp objects
//  DONE - Make executable/window names mesh better together?  Need a map/lookup table or something? - JUST USE PID YA IDIOT
//
//
//Data Issues:
//  Save fps and frametime and other stats as well?
//  Add graph functionality
//  Put elapsed time in log file
//  Clear log files and put a configurable(?) cap on the number allowed
//  Keep track of total tests performed in a config file vs. looking for existing log files and picking up from there?
//      How many tests should we allow total? 100? 
//      Would it be fine if SysLat overwrote the tests every time it was restarted? ...I think it would
//
//
//Menu:
//  Enumerate all 3D programs that RTSS can run in and display them in a menu
//  Fix COM port change settings
//  Add lots more menu options - USB options, debug output, data upload, RTSS options(text color)
//  Box position manual override toggle
//
//
//Anti-Fraud:
//  Create new dynamic build/installation process in order to obscure some code
//  Think about hardware/software signatures for uploading data? This probably needs more consideration on the web side
//  Obscure most functionality(things that don't need to be optimized) into DLLs(requires a new build/installation process)
//  (Anti-Fraud, Optimization, and Data)Instead of recording certain variables on every measurement(such as RTSS XY position) record them once at the start and once at the end
//
//
//Optimization:
//  Move data update at the end of the CreateDrawingThread function into a different thread(or co-routine?)
//  Calculating the position of the box before we draw it adds unnecessary delay(?)
//  Make flashing square resizeable
//
//
//Organizational Issues:
//  Clean up(or get rid of) static vars in SysLat_SoftwareDlg class
//  Clean up the refresh function a bit more by making some init functionality conditional
//  Attempt to get rid of most Windows type names like CString, BOOL, and INT(DWORD?)
//  Attempt to use a single style of string instead of "string", "char*", and "CString".
//  Look further into Windows style guides & straighten out all member var names with "m_" and the type, or do away with it completely
//  Look into file organization for .h and .cpp files because the repo is a mess(though it's fine in VS because of "filters")
//  Look into class naming schemes and organization - make sure dialog classes end in "dlg"(?)
//  Check whether or not my void "initialization" methods need to return ints or bools for success/failure or if I can just leave them as void

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Major Bugs:
//  DONE - (hid the error)The SysLat RTSSClient object cannot obtain the "0th" RTSS OSD slot when restarting a test
//  Issue when switching COM ports to an existing device that isn't SysLat and back
//  DONE - Arrow key functionality has been optimized away somehow
//  
//
//Minor Bugs:
//  SysLat may not play nicely with other applications that use RTSS such as MSI Afterburner, or with advanced RTSS setups
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const int ID_COMPORT_START = 2000;
const int ID_COMPORT_END = 2099;
const int ID_RTSSAPP_START = 2100;
const int ID_RTSSAPP_END = 2199;
const int WM_STMESSAGE = WM_USER + 1;

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

//As a non-static non-member variable? Is this a good idea? Need to at least remove the "m_" from the var name... Does this make it global??
SysLatPreferences   SLPref;
#define SysLatOpt SLPref.m_SysLatOptions
#define PrivacyOpt SLPref.m_PrivacyOptions
#define DebugOpt SLPref.m_DebugOptions
#define RTSSOpt SLPref.m_RTSSOptions

NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
int dotCounter = 0;

//Define static variables - these should probably be done as inline or something... inlining is supposed to be available in C++17 and above, but Visual Studio throws a fit when I try to inline these.
//also, I should probably move most of them to be global variables and NOT member variables
CString CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_strStatus = "";
unsigned int CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_LoopCounterRefresh = 0;
unsigned int CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_loopSize = 0xFFFFFFFF;
CString CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_updateString = "";
CString CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_strError = "";
std::shared_ptr<CSysLatData> CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_pOperatingSLD = std::make_shared<CSysLatData>(); //does this need to be a unique_ptr?
CString CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_strBlack = "<C=000000><B=10,10><C>";
CString CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_strWhite = "<C=FFFFFF><B=10,10><C>";
DWORD CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_sysLatOwnedSlot = 0;
DWORD CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::m_AppArraySize = 0;

//Windows Dialog inherited function overrides
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CSysLat_SoftwareDlg dialog
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::CSysLat_SoftwareDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg)
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
    // Note that LoadIcon does not require a subsequent DestroyIcon in Win32

    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    m_strStatus = "";
    m_strInstallPath = "";

    m_bMultiLineOutput = TRUE;
    m_bFormatTags = TRUE;
    m_bFillGraphs = FALSE;
    m_bConnected = FALSE;
}
CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::~CSysLat_SoftwareDlg() {
    SLPref.WritePreferences();
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg)
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CSysLat_SoftwareDlg message handlers
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg, CDialogEx)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CSysLat_SoftwareDlg)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_DESTROY()
    ON_COMMAND(ID_TOOLS_EXPORTDATA, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::ExportData)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_TOOLS_UPLOADDATA, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::UploadData)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_DEBUGMODE, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::DebugMode)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_TESTUPLOADMODE, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::TestUploadMode)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_DISPLAYSYSLATINOSD, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::DisplaySysLatInOSD)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_TOOLS_NEWTEST, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::ReInitThread)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OpenPreferences)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_TOOLS_TESTCONTROL, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OpenTestCtrl)
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(ID_COMPORT_START, ID_COMPORT_END, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnComPortChanged)
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(ID_RTSSAPP_START, ID_RTSSAPP_END, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnTargetWindowChanged)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_STMESSAGE, CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnSTMessage)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_color = RGB(136, 217, 242);
    m_brush.CreateSolidBrush(m_color);

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, pathToSysLat, MAX_PATH);

    CWnd* pMainDlg = GetDlgItem(IDD_SYSLAT_SOFTWARE_DIALOG);

    if (pMainDlg)
    {
        pMainDlg->GetClientRect(&m_clientRect);
    }

    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);

    CWnd* pPlaceholder = GetDlgItem(IDC_PLACEHOLDER);

    if (pPlaceholder)
    {
        CRect rect;
        pPlaceholder->GetClientRect(&rect);

        if (!m_richEditCtrl.Create(WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL, rect, this, 0))
            return FALSE;

        m_font.CreateFont(-11, 0, 0, 0, FW_REGULAR, 0, 0, 0, BALTIC_CHARSET, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Courier New");
        m_richEditCtrl.SetFont(&m_font);
    }
    
    if (PrivacyOpt.m_bFirstRun) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, "This appears to be the first time you've run SysLat from this directory. Please set your privacy options.", "SysLat First Run", MB_OK);
        OpenPreferences();
        PrivacyOpt.m_bFirstRun = false;
    }

    
    if (PrivacyOpt.m_bRunOnStartup) {
        SetSURegValue(pathToSysLat);
    }
    else {
        SetSURegValue("");
    }
    
    //m_bTestUploadMode = true;
    if(PrivacyOpt.m_bAutoCheckUpdates){
        CheckUpdate();
    }
    

    m_nTimerID = SetTimer(0x1234, 1000, NULL);  //Used by OnTimer function to refresh dialog box & OSD
    time(&m_elapsedTimeStart);                  //Used to keep track of test length

    m_hardwareID.ExportData(SysLatOpt.m_LogDir);
    m_machineInfo.ExportData(SysLatOpt.m_LogDir);

    Refresh();

    unsigned threadID;
    m_drawingThreadHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, CreateDrawingThread, &myCounter, 0, &threadID);
    SetThreadPriority(m_drawingThreadHandle, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);//31 is(apparently?) the highest possible thread priority - may be bad because it could cause deadlock using a loop? Need to read more here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == SC_MINIMIZE)
    {
        nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
        nid.hWnd = m_hWnd;
        nid.uID = 100;
        nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
        nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_STMESSAGE;
        nid.hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
        strcpy_s(nid.szTip, "SysLat");
        nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);

        ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
        // Minimizing, post to main dialogue also.
        AfxGetMainWnd()->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
    }
    //else if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == SC_CLOSE) {
    //  nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    //  nid.hWnd = m_hWnd;
    //  nid.uID = 100;
    //  nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
    //  nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_STMESSAGE;
    //  nid.hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    //  strcpy_s(nid.szTip, "SysLat");
    //  nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
    //  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);

    //  ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
    //  // Minimizing, post to main dialogue also.
    //  AfxGetMainWnd()->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
    //}
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        //THIS CODE FOR THE MINIMIZE BUTTON IS NO LONGER(NEVER WAS??) NEEDED??
        //CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        //SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, (WPARAM)dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0);

        //// Center icon in client rectangle
        //int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        //int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        //CRect rect;
        //GetClientRect(&rect);
        //int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        //int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        //dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

HCURSOR CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return (HCURSOR)m_hIcon;
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
    Refresh();
    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnDestroy()
{
    if (m_nTimerID)
        KillTimer(m_nTimerID);

    m_nTimerID = NULL;

    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, m_hWnd, WM_TIMER, WM_TIMER, PM_REMOVE));

    TerminateThread(m_drawingThreadHandle, 0); //Does exit code need to be 0 for this?
    m_SysLatStatsClient.ReleaseOSD();
    //m_pOperatingSLD->CloseSLDMutex();

    CDialogEx::OnDestroy();
}
LRESULT CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnSTMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

    if (lParam == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK){
        if (IsIconic()) {
            ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
            ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &nid);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//Dialog functions
string CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::GetProcessNameFromPID(DWORD processID) {
    string ret;
    HANDLE Handle = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        processID
    );
    if (Handle)
    {
        DWORD buffSize = 1024;
        CHAR Buffer[1024];
        if (QueryFullProcessImageName(Handle, 0, Buffer, &buffSize))
        {
            ret = strrchr(Buffer, '\\') + 1; // I can't believe this works
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error GetModuleBaseName : %lu", GetLastError());
        }
        CloseHandle(Handle);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error OpenProcess : %lu", GetLastError());
    }
    return ret;
}
string CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    char wnd_title[256];
    CWnd* pWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    ::GetWindowText((HWND)*pWnd, wnd_title, 256); //Had to use scope resolution because this function is defined in both WinUser.h and afxwin.h
    return wnd_title;
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::ProcessNameTrim(string& processName, string& activeWindowTitle){
    size_t pos = processName.find(".exe");
    if (pos != string::npos) {
        processName.replace(pos, processName.size(), "");
    }
    while ((pos = processName.find(" ")) != string::npos) {
        processName.replace(pos, 1, "");
    }
    std::transform(processName.begin(), processName.end(), processName.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    while ((pos = activeWindowTitle.find(" ")) != string::npos) {
        activeWindowTitle.replace(pos, 1, "");
    }
    std::transform(activeWindowTitle.begin(), activeWindowTitle.end(), activeWindowTitle.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
}
BOOL CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (pMsg->wParam)
        {
        case VK_F11:
            ReInitThread();
            return TRUE;
        case ' ':
            if (!m_bConnected)
            {
                if (!CRTSSClient::m_strInstallPath.IsEmpty())
                    ShellExecute(GetSafeHwnd(), "open", CRTSSClient::m_strInstallPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            }
            return TRUE;
        case VK_UP:
            if (RTSSOpt.m_internalY > 0) {
                RTSSOpt.m_internalY--;
            }
            //else appendError ??
            RTSSOpt.m_bPositionManualOverride = true;
            return TRUE;
        case VK_DOWN:
            if (RTSSOpt.m_internalY < 255) {
                RTSSOpt.m_internalY++;
            }
            RTSSOpt.m_bPositionManualOverride = true;
            return TRUE;
        case VK_LEFT:
            if (RTSSOpt.m_internalX > 0) {
                RTSSOpt.m_internalX--;
            }
            RTSSOpt.m_bPositionManualOverride = true;
            return TRUE;
        case VK_RIGHT:
            if (RTSSOpt.m_internalX < 255) {
                RTSSOpt.m_internalX++;
            }
            RTSSOpt.m_bPositionManualOverride = true;
            return TRUE;
        case 'R':
            CRTSSClient::SetProfileProperty("", "BaseColor", 0xFF0000);
            return TRUE;
        case 'G':
            CRTSSClient::SetProfileProperty("", "BaseColor", 0x00FF00);
            return TRUE;
        case 'B':
            CRTSSClient::SetProfileProperty("", "BaseColor", 0x0000FF);
            return TRUE;
        case 'F':
            if (m_bConnected)
            {
                m_bFormatTags = !m_bFormatTags;
                Refresh();
            }
            break;
        case 'I':
            if (m_bConnected)
            {
                m_bFillGraphs = !m_bFillGraphs;
                Refresh();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::Refresh()
{
    //Had to add this section because it was initializing fine in debug mode, but then initializing COMPortCount too fast in release mode??? Probably some stupid issue with my debug macros...
    CMenu* MainMenu = GetMenu();
    CMenu* SettingsMenu = MainMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
    CMenu* ComPortMenu = SettingsMenu->GetSubMenu(0);
    char menuCString[256];
    MainMenu->GetMenuString(ID_USBPORT_PLACEHOLDER, (LPSTR)menuCString, 256, (UINT)MF_BYCOMMAND);
    
    if (strcmp(menuCString, "Placeholder") == 0) {
        m_COMPortCount = 0;
    }

    CUSBController usbController;
    usbController.EnumSerialPorts(m_COMPortInfo, FALSE);
    if (m_COMPortInfo.GetSize() != m_COMPortCount) {
        R_DynamicComPortMenu();
    }

    if (m_bConnected) {//m_bConnected is never set to true??
        DWORD AppArraySize = CRTSSClient::GetAppArray();
        if (m_AppArraySize != AppArraySize) {
            R_DynamicAppMenu();
            m_AppArraySize = AppArraySize;
            DEBUG_PRINT("AppArraySize: " + to_string(AppArraySize))
        }
    }

    if (!(CRTSSClient::m_profileInterface.IsInitialized())) {
        CRTSSClient::InitRTSSInterface();
    }
    RTSSOpt.m_positionX = CRTSSClient::GetProfileProperty("", "PositionX");
    RTSSOpt.m_positionY = CRTSSClient::GetProfileProperty("", "PositionY");
    if (m_bConnected && !m_bRTSSInitConfig) {
        R_GetRTSSConfigs();
    }
    else {
        m_bRTSSInitConfig = false;
    }
    
    m_strStatus = "";
    if (!R_SysLatStats()) return;
    if (m_bDebugMode) {
        R_Position();
        R_ProcessNames();
    }
    
    R_StrOSD();
    
    if (!m_bSysLatInOSD) { //need to add another condition to make this only happen once so that it will clear whatever exists in the buffer... or maybe use the releaseOSD function properly? IDK
        m_SysLatStatsClient.UpdateOSD("");
    }

    //Need to make a new function & boolean for displaying controls/hints
    if (CRTSSClient::m_profileInterface.IsInitialized())
    {
        m_strStatus += "\n\n-Press <Up>,<Down>,<Left>,<Right> to change OSD position in global profile";
        if (DebugOpt.m_bSysLatInOSD) {
            m_strStatus += "\n-Press <R>,<G>,<B> to change OSD color in global profile";
        }
    }
    
    if (!m_strError.IsEmpty())
    {
        m_strStatus += "\n\nErrors:";
        m_strStatus.Append(m_strError);
        m_strError = "";
    }

    m_richEditCtrl.SetWindowText(m_strStatus);
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_GetRTSSConfigs() {
    m_dwSharedMemoryVersion = CRTSSClient::GetSharedMemoryVersion();
    m_dwMaxTextSize = (m_dwSharedMemoryVersion >= 0x00020007) ? sizeof(RTSS_SHARED_MEMORY::RTSS_SHARED_MEMORY_OSD_ENTRY().szOSDEx) : sizeof(RTSS_SHARED_MEMORY::RTSS_SHARED_MEMORY_OSD_ENTRY().szOSD);
    m_bFormatTagsSupported = (m_dwSharedMemoryVersion >= 0x0002000b);   //text format tags are supported for shared memory v2.11 and higher
    m_bObjTagsSupported = (m_dwSharedMemoryVersion >= 0x0002000c);      //embedded object tags are supporoted for shared memory v2.12 and higher
    m_bRTSSInitConfig = true;
}

BOOL CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_SysLatStats() {

    //this timer stuff definitely needs to be in the SLD
    time(&m_elapsedTimeEnd);
    double dif = difftime(m_elapsedTimeEnd, m_elapsedTimeStart);
    int minutes = static_cast<int>(dif) / 60;
    int seconds = static_cast<int>(dif) % 60;

    auto& data = m_pOperatingSLD->GetData();

    if (minutes >= SysLatOpt.m_maxTestDuration) {
        ReInitThread();
    }

    double measurementsPerSecond = data.m_statistics.counter / dif;
    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("Elapsed Time: %02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    if (m_pOperatingSLD->GetSystemLatency() < 500) { //using "c_str()" here because "stoi(m_pOperatingSLD->GetStringResult())" was getting immediate exceptions for some reason...
        m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nSystem Latency: %i", m_pOperatingSLD->GetSystemLatency());
    }
    else {
        m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nSystem Latency: Waiting");
        if (dotCounter == 1) {
            m_strStatus.AppendFormat(".");
        }
        else if (dotCounter == 2) {
            m_strStatus.AppendFormat("..");
        }
        else if (dotCounter == 3) {
            m_strStatus.AppendFormat("...");
        }
    }

    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nLoop Counter : %d", data.m_statistics.counter);

    if (isnan(measurementsPerSecond)) {
        m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nMeasurements Per Second: 0.00");
    }
    else {
        m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nMeasurements Per Second: %.2f", measurementsPerSecond); //This value should probably be in the SLD...
    }

    if (data.m_statistics.average < 500) {
        m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nSystem Latency Average: %.2f", data.m_statistics.average);
    }
    else {
        m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nSystem Latency Average: Waiting");
        if (dotCounter == 1) {
            m_strStatus.AppendFormat(".");
        }
        else if (dotCounter == 2) {
            m_strStatus.AppendFormat("..");
        }
        else if (dotCounter == 3) {
            m_strStatus.AppendFormat("...");
        }
    }
    dotCounter++;
    if (dotCounter >= 4) {
        dotCounter = 0;
    }

    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nLoop Counter EVR(expected value range, 3-100): %d ", data.m_statisticsEVR.counter);
    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nSystem Latency Average(EVR): %.2f", data.m_statisticsEVR.average);

    return true; //this return value needs to change or be removed
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_Position() {
    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\n\nClients num: %d", CRTSSClient::clientsNum);
    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nSysLat Owned Slot: %d", m_sysLatOwnedSlot);
    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nPositionX: %d", RTSSOpt.m_positionX);
    m_strStatus.AppendFormat("\nPositionY: %d", RTSSOpt.m_positionY);
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_ProcessNames() {
    DWORD dwLastForegroundAppProcessID = CRTSSClient::GetLastForegroundAppID();
    m_strStatus.Append("\n\nLast RTSS Foreground App Name: ");
    string processName = GetProcessNameFromPID(dwLastForegroundAppProcessID);
    m_strStatus += processName.c_str();
    m_strStatus.Append("\nCurrently active window: ");
    string activeWindowTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();
    m_strStatus += activeWindowTitle.c_str();
    ProcessNameTrim(processName, activeWindowTitle);
    m_strStatus.Append("\nTrimmed:");
    m_strStatus += processName.c_str();
    m_strStatus.Append("\nTrimmed:");
    m_strStatus += activeWindowTitle.c_str();
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_StrOSD() {
    //BOOL bTruncated = FALSE;
    string strOSD;// = strOSDBuilder.Get(bTruncated);
    strOSD += m_pOperatingSLD->GetSystemLatency();
    if (!(strOSD.size() == 0))
    {
        bool bResult = m_SysLatStatsClient.UpdateOSD(strOSD.c_str());

        m_bConnected = bResult;

        if (bResult)
        {
            m_strStatus += "\nTarget Window: ";
            m_strStatus += (SysLatOpt.m_targetApp).c_str();
            /*
            m_strStatus += "\n\nThe following text is being forwarded to OSD:\nFrom SysLat client: " + m_updateString + "\nFrom SysLatStats client: " + strOSD;
            
            if (m_bFormatTagsSupported)
                m_strStatus += "\n-Press <F> to toggle OSD text formatting tags";
            if (m_bFormatTagsSupported)
                m_strStatus += "\n-Press <I> to toggle graphs fill mode";
            */
            //if (bTruncated)
            //  AppendError("Warning: The text is too long to be displayed in OSD, some info has been truncated!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (CRTSSClient::m_strInstallPath.IsEmpty())
                AppendError("Error: Failed to connect to RTSS shared memory!\nHints:\n-Install RivaTuner Statistics Server");
            else
                AppendError("Error: Failed to connect to RTSS shared memory!\nHints:\n-Press <Space> to start RivaTuner Statistics Server");
        }
        //TODO: 1-6-21 - I THOUGHT I FREAKING FIXED THIS??
        if (m_sysLatOwnedSlot != 0) { 
            //AppendError("The SysLat client is unable to occupy RTSS client slot 0.\nThis may cause issues with the blinking square appearing in the corner.\nTo resolve this error try one of the following:\n\t1. Close other applications that use RTSS(such as MSI Afterburner)\n\t2. Restart RTSS\n\t3. Restart the testing phase(by pressing <F11>).");
        }
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_DynamicComPortMenu()
{
    CMenu* MainMenu = GetMenu();
    CMenu* SettingsMenu = MainMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
    CMenu* ComPortMenu = SettingsMenu->GetSubMenu(0);

    if (ComPortMenu)
    {
        BOOL appended = false;
        BOOL deleted = false;
        m_COMPortCount = 0;
        
        for(auto i = 0; i < m_COMPortInfo.GetSize(); i++) {
            ComPortMenu->DeleteMenu(ID_COMPORT_START + m_COMPortCount, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            if (m_COMPortCount < ID_COMPORT_END - ID_COMPORT_START) {
                string usb_info = m_COMPortInfo[i].strFriendlyName;
                DEBUG_PRINT("Friendly Name: " + usb_info)

                appended = ComPortMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_COMPORT_START + m_COMPortCount, m_COMPortInfo[i].strFriendlyName);
                string menuString = m_COMPortInfo[i].strFriendlyName;
                size_t pos = menuString.rfind("(");
                menuString.replace(0, pos + 1, "");
                pos = menuString.rfind(")");
                menuString.replace(pos, menuString.size(), "");

                if (strcmp(menuString.c_str(), SysLatOpt.m_PortSpecifier.c_str()) == 0) {
                    MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_COMPORT_START + m_COMPortCount, MF_CHECKED);
                }

                m_COMPortCount++;
            }
            else { //catch or throw errors here maybe?
                break;
            }
        }
        deleted = ComPortMenu->DeleteMenu(ID_USBPORT_PLACEHOLDER, MF_BYCOMMAND);

        DEBUG_PRINT(("String appended: " + to_string(appended)).c_str())
        DEBUG_PRINT(("Placeholder deleted: " + to_string(deleted)).c_str())

    }
    DrawMenuBar();

}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::R_DynamicAppMenu()
{
    CMenu* MainMenu = GetMenu();
    CMenu* SettingsMenu = MainMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
    CMenu* TargetAppMenu = SettingsMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
    
    if (TargetAppMenu)
    {
        BOOL appended = false;
        BOOL deleted = false;
        int count = 0;
        for (auto const& [pid, pName] : CRTSSClient::m_vszAppArr) {
            SettingsMenu->DeleteMenu(ID_RTSSAPP_START + count, MF_BYCOMMAND); 
            if (count < ID_RTSSAPP_END - ID_RTSSAPP_START) {
                if (pName != "SysLat_Software") {
                    string id_name =  pName + " (" + to_string(pid) + ")";
                    appended = TargetAppMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_RTSSAPP_START + count, id_name.c_str());

                    if (strcmp(pName.c_str(), SysLatOpt.m_targetApp.c_str()) == 0) {
                        MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_RTSSAPP_START + count, MF_CHECKED);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else { //error here?
                break;
            }
        }
        deleted = TargetAppMenu->DeleteMenu(ID_TARGETWINDOW_PLACEHOLDER, MF_BYCOMMAND);

        DEBUG_PRINT(("String appended: " + to_string(appended)).c_str())
        DEBUG_PRINT(("Placeholder deleted: " + to_string(deleted)).c_str())
    }
    DrawMenuBar();
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::AppendError(const CString& error)
{
    m_strError.Append("\n");
    m_strError.Append(error);
    m_strError.Append("\n");
}

//SysLat thread functions
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::ReInitThread() {
    m_loopSize = 0;
    WaitForSingleObjectEx(m_drawingThreadHandle, INFINITE, false);
    m_pOperatingSLD->m_targetApp = SysLatOpt.m_targetApp;
    m_pOperatingSLD->SetEndTime();
    m_loopSize = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    //Reset the timer 
    time(&m_elapsedTimeStart); 
    myCounter = 0;

    //Save the data from the test that just completed in a vector of "SysLatData"s
    m_vpPreviousSLD.push_back(m_pOperatingSLD);
    m_pOperatingSLD = std::make_shared<CSysLatData>();

    //Restart the thread
    m_drawingThreadHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, CreateDrawingThread, &myCounter, 0, 0);
    SetThreadPriority(m_drawingThreadHandle, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);

    //Convert the previous data to JSON
    m_vpPreviousSLD.back()->CreateJSONSLD();

    //Export and upload the data if enabled
    if (PrivacyOpt.m_bAutoExportLogs && SysLatOpt.m_maxLogs > 0) {
        ExportData();
    }
    if (PrivacyOpt.m_bAutoUploadLogs) {
        UploadData();
    }
}
unsigned int __stdcall CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::CreateDrawingThread(void* data) //this is probably dangerous, right?
{
    int TIMEOUT = 5; //this should probably be a defined constant
    int serialReadData = 0;
    string  sysLatResults;
    CRTSSClient sysLatClient("SysLat", 0);
    m_sysLatOwnedSlot = sysLatClient.ownedSlot;
    //the following should not be here because if RTSS isn't running when this is hit, the version is "0"
    m_pOperatingSLD->m_RTSSVersion = "v" + to_string(sysLatClient.sharedMemoryVersion);
    

    CUSBController usbController;
    HANDLE hPort = usbController.OpenComPort(SysLatOpt.m_PortSpecifier.c_str());

    while (!usbController.IsComPortOpened(hPort) && m_loopSize > 0)
    {
        hPort = usbController.OpenComPort(SysLatOpt.m_PortSpecifier.c_str());
        AppendError("Failed to open COM port: ");
        AppendError(SysLatOpt.m_PortSpecifier.c_str());
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    DrawSquare(sysLatClient, m_strBlack);

    LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicrosecondsDraw, ElapsedMicrosecondsExtra, Frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);
    vector<long long> timeVectorDraw, timeVectorExtra;

    for (unsigned int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < m_loopSize; loopCounter++)
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);


        time_t start = time(NULL);
        while (serialReadData != 65 && time(NULL) - start < TIMEOUT) {
            serialReadData = usbController.ReadByte(hPort);
        }
        DrawSquare(sysLatClient, m_strWhite);
        while (serialReadData != 66 && time(NULL) - start < TIMEOUT) {
            serialReadData = usbController.ReadByte(hPort);
        }
        DrawSquare(sysLatClient, m_strBlack);
        sysLatResults = "";
        while (serialReadData != 67 && time(NULL) - start < TIMEOUT) {
            serialReadData = usbController.ReadByte(hPort);
            if (serialReadData != 67 && serialReadData != 65 && serialReadData != 66) {
                sysLatResults += (char)serialReadData;
            }
        }

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
        ElapsedMicrosecondsDraw.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
        ElapsedMicrosecondsDraw.QuadPart *= 1000000;
        ElapsedMicrosecondsDraw.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

        
        timeVectorDraw.push_back(ElapsedMicrosecondsDraw.QuadPart);



        //I think everything below(ESPECIALLY the "UpdateSLD" method) should be happening in a different thread so that the serial reads can continue uninterrupted - could the following be a coroutine?
        // 1-3-2021 thinking on this more, I need the following work to be "queued" up for the main thread... Not sure what the best way to accomplish that is.
        // 1-13-2021 - After some extensive testing, these functions are taking anywhere from 100-500 microseconds(half of a milllisecond) to complete, and should not be affecting the test accuracy by very much... still needs to be fixed though
        //push_back() lots of this stuff to a vector and then have the Refresh(?) function handle it?
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

        string processName = GetProcessNameFromPID(CRTSSClient::GetLastForegroundAppID());
        string activeWindowTitle;
        if (loopCounter < m_loopSize) { //this was for a really strange issue when trying to end the thread.
            activeWindowTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle();
        }
        else {
            activeWindowTitle = "";
        }
        ProcessNameTrim(processName, activeWindowTitle);

        //This does the same as the block above, but uses PID instead of a bunch of unnecessary string editing.
        //Both of the following work? I bet there's another(probably better way) to use the class name instead of the macro-definition(?) "_WINUSER_".
        //HWND hWnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
        HWND hWnd = _WINUSER_::GetForegroundWindow();
        DWORD PID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &PID);
        
        DWORD RTSS_Pid = CRTSSClient::GetLastForegroundAppID();
        
        m_pOperatingSLD->UpdateSLD(loopCounter, sysLatResults, processName, activeWindowTitle, PID, RTSS_Pid);

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
        ElapsedMicrosecondsExtra.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
        ElapsedMicrosecondsExtra.QuadPart *= 1000000;
        ElapsedMicrosecondsExtra.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

        timeVectorExtra.push_back(ElapsedMicrosecondsExtra.QuadPart);

        //DEBUG_PRINT("Draw: \t" + to_string(ElapsedMicrosecondsDraw.QuadPart) + "\tExtra: \t" + to_string(ElapsedMicrosecondsExtra.QuadPart))
    }

    long long totalMicroseconds = 0;
    long long averageMicroseconds = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < timeVectorDraw.size(); i++) {
        totalMicroseconds += timeVectorDraw[i];
    }
    double averageMilliseconds;
    if (timeVectorDraw.size() != 0) {
        averageMicroseconds = totalMicroseconds / timeVectorDraw.size();
        averageMilliseconds = averageMicroseconds / 1000;
        //DEBUG_PRINT("Draw Total microseconds: " + to_string(totalMicroseconds))
        //DEBUG_PRINT("Draw Average microseconds: " + to_string(averageMicroseconds))
        //DEBUG_PRINT("Draw Average milliseconds: " + to_string(averageMilliseconds))
    }

    totalMicroseconds = 0;
    averageMicroseconds = 0;

    if (timeVectorExtra.size() != 0) {
        for (auto i = 0; i < timeVectorExtra.size(); i++) {
            totalMicroseconds += timeVectorExtra[i];
        }

        averageMicroseconds = totalMicroseconds / timeVectorExtra.size();
        averageMilliseconds = averageMicroseconds / 1000;
    }
    //DEBUG_PRINT("Extra Total microseconds: " + to_string(totalMicroseconds))
    //DEBUG_PRINT("Extra Average microseconds: " + to_string(averageMicroseconds))
    //DEBUG_PRINT("Extra Average milliseconds: " + to_string(averageMilliseconds))

    usbController.CloseComPort(hPort);
    sysLatClient.ReleaseOSD();

    return 0;
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::DrawSquare(CRTSSClient sysLatClient, CString& colorString)
{
    m_updateString = "";
    //The following conditional is FAR from perfect... In order for it to work properly I may need to count the number of rows and columns(in zoomed pixel units?) and use that value. 
    if (sysLatClient.ownedSlot == 0 && !RTSSOpt.m_bPositionManualOverride) {
        if ((int)RTSSOpt.m_positionX < 0) {
            RTSSOpt.m_internalX = 0;
        }
        if ((int)RTSSOpt.m_positionY < 0) {
            //y = CRTSSClient::clientsNum * 20;
            RTSSOpt.m_internalY = 20;
        }
        m_updateString.AppendFormat("<P=%d,%d>", RTSSOpt.m_internalX, RTSSOpt.m_internalY);
        m_updateString += colorString;
        m_updateString += "<P=0,0>";
    }
    else if (RTSSOpt.m_bPositionManualOverride) {
        m_updateString.AppendFormat("<P=%d,%d>", RTSSOpt.m_internalX, RTSSOpt.m_internalY);
        m_updateString += colorString;
        m_updateString += "<P=0,0>";
    }
    else {
        m_updateString += colorString;
    }
    
    sysLatClient.UpdateOSD(m_updateString);
}

//Dialog menu functions
//Tools
//The version without a parameter uses the other classes "ExportData" functions
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::ExportData()
{
    if (m_vpPreviousSLD.size() > 0) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_vpPreviousSLD.size(); i++) {
            //The following code is for testing file export changes - maybe I should make it run only in debugMode?
            //Json::Value newJSON;
            //const Json::Value* const sources[] = {
            //  &m_previousSLD[i]->m_JSONsld,
            //  &m_hardwareID.HardwareIDJSON,
            //  &m_machineInfo.MachineInfoJSON
            //};
            //for (const Json::Value* src : sources)
            //  for (auto srcIt = src->begin(); srcIt != src->end(); ++srcIt)
            //      newJSON[srcIt.name()] = *srcIt;
            //ExportData(newJSON);

            if (!m_vpPreviousSLD[i]->m_bDataExported) {
                m_vpPreviousSLD[i]->ExportData(i, SysLatOpt.m_LogDir, SysLatOpt.m_maxLogs);
            }

            //else {
            //  string error = "Data from test " + to_string(i) + " already exported."; //this error message is garbage in every way
            //  AppendError(error.c_str());
            //}

        }
    }
    else {
        //this is one of the errors that only appears for a few seconds and then dissapears... open an error dialog instead maybe?
        AppendError("No tests have completed yet. \nPress F11 to begin a new test(ending the current test), or wait for the current test to finish. \nYou can change the test size in the menu."); // (Not yet you can't lol)
    }
}
//This overload with a "Json::Value" as a parameter does the export here using streams
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::ExportData(Json::Value stuffToExport) {
    std::ofstream exportData;
    exportData.open("./logs/exportSLD.json");

    if (exportData.is_open()) {
        exportData << stuffToExport;
    }
    else {
        DEBUG_PRINT("\nError exporting JSON SLD file.\n")
    }

    exportData.close();
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::UploadData()
{
    //I DIDN'T WANT TO SET THE API TARGET LIKE THIS - HAD TO DO IT THIS WAY BECAUSE FUNCTIONS THAT ARE USED BY DIALOG MENU BUTTONS CAN'T HAVE PARAMETERS <.<
    const char* APItarget = "/api/benchmarkData";
    
    if (m_vpPreviousSLD.size() > 0) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_vpPreviousSLD.size(); i++) {
            http::response<http::string_body> uploadStatus;
            if (!m_vpPreviousSLD[i]->m_bDataUploaded) {

                Json::Value newJSON;
                const Json::Value* const sources[] = {
                    &m_vpPreviousSLD[i]->GetJSONData(),
                    &m_hardwareID.HardwareIDJSON,
                    &m_machineInfo.MachineInfoJSON
                };
                for (const Json::Value* src : sources)
                    for (auto srcIt = src->begin(); srcIt != src->end(); ++srcIt)
                        newJSON[srcIt.name()] = *srcIt;

                if (m_bTestUploadMode) {
                    uploadStatus = upload_data(newJSON, APItarget);
                }
                else {
                    uploadStatus = upload_data_secure(newJSON, APItarget);
                }
                m_vpPreviousSLD[i]->m_bDataUploaded = true; //need to make uploadStatus return a bool or something and use it to set this var
            }

            /*else {
                string error = "Data from test " + to_string(i) + " already uploaded.";
                AppendError(error.c_str());
            }*/

        }
    }
    else {
        //this is one of the errors that only appears for a few seconds and then dissapears... open an error dialog instead maybe?
        AppendError("No tests have completed yet. \nPress F11 to begin a new test(ending the current test), or wait for the current test to finish. \nYou can change the test size in the menu."); // (Not yet you can't lol)
    }
}

void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnComPortChanged(UINT nID)
{
    int nButton = nID - ID_COMPORT_START;
    ASSERT(nButton >= 0 && nButton < 100);

    CMenu* MainMenu = GetMenu();

    int count = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < m_COMPortInfo.GetSize(); i++) {
        if (count == nButton) {
            MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(nID, MF_CHECKED);

            char menuCString[256];
            MainMenu->GetMenuString(nID, (LPSTR)menuCString, 256, (UINT)MF_BYCOMMAND);
            string menuString = menuCString;
            size_t pos = menuString.rfind("(");
            menuString.replace(0, pos + 1, "");
            pos = menuString.rfind(")");
            menuString.replace(pos, menuString.size(), "");

            SysLatOpt.m_PortSpecifier = menuString;
        }
        else {
            MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(count + ID_COMPORT_START, MF_UNCHECKED);
        }
        count++;
    }

    //1-6-21: getting an error on my machine when going from COM1 to COM4(they are currently 2 different devices) & it's clearly being caused by recreating the thread(and therefore the USB connection)
    ReInitThread();
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnTargetWindowChanged(UINT nID)
{
    int nButton = nID - ID_RTSSAPP_START;
    ASSERT(nButton >= 0 && nButton < 100);

    CMenu* MainMenu = GetMenu();

    int count = 0;
    for (auto const& [pid, pName] : CRTSSClient::m_vszAppArr) {
        if (count == nButton) {
            MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(nID, MF_CHECKED);

            char menuCString[256];
            MainMenu->GetMenuString(nID, (LPSTR)menuCString, 256, (UINT)MF_BYCOMMAND);
            string menuString = menuCString;
            size_t pos = menuString.rfind(" ");
            menuString.replace(pos, menuString.size(), "");

            SysLatOpt.m_targetApp = menuString;
        }
        else {
            MainMenu->CheckMenuItem(count + 1100, MF_UNCHECKED);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::DebugMode() {
    CMenu* settingsMenu = GetMenu();
    if (m_bDebugMode) {
        settingsMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_SETTINGS_DEBUGMODE, MF_UNCHECKED);
        m_bDebugMode = false;
    }
    else {
        settingsMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_SETTINGS_DEBUGMODE, MF_CHECKED);
        m_bDebugMode = true;
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::TestUploadMode() {
    CMenu* settingsMenu = GetMenu();
    if (m_bTestUploadMode) {    
        settingsMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_SETTINGS_TESTUPLOADMODE, MF_UNCHECKED);
        m_bTestUploadMode = false;
    }
    else {
        settingsMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_SETTINGS_TESTUPLOADMODE, MF_CHECKED);
        m_bTestUploadMode = true;
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::DisplaySysLatInOSD() {
    //this needs to default to "on" if you have a version with no LCD on "off" if your SysLat does have an LCD
    CMenu* settingsMenu = GetMenu();
    if (m_bSysLatInOSD) {
        settingsMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_SETTINGS_DISPLAYSYSLATINOSD, MF_UNCHECKED);
        m_bSysLatInOSD = false;
    }
    else {
        settingsMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_SETTINGS_DISPLAYSYSLATINOSD, MF_CHECKED);
        m_bSysLatInOSD = true;
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OpenPreferences() {
    PreferencesDlg preferencesDlg(&SLPref);
    preferencesDlg.DoModal();

    //this should probably be set somewhere else...
    if (PrivacyOpt.m_bRunOnStartup) {
        SetSURegValue(pathToSysLat);
    }
    else {
        SetSURegValue("");
    }
}
void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OpenTestCtrl() {
    TestCtrl testCtrl(&m_vpPreviousSLD);
    testCtrl.DoModal();
}

/*
    //init some settings to global(?) profile - probably- scratch that, DEFINITELY need to move these
    //SetProfileProperty("", "BaseColor", 0xFFFFFF);
    //SetProfileProperty("", "BgndColor", 0x000000); //this value isn't actually modifiable in RTSS lol
    //SetProfileProperty("", "FillColor", 0x000000);
    //SetProfileProperty("", "ZoomRatio", 2);
    //SetProfileProperty("", "RefreshPeriod", 0); //found this property by looking at the plaintext of the RTSSHooks.dll.  Doesn't appear to change the value.  Also attempted to use the "Inc" function as well, but it also failed.
    //SetProfileProperty("", "RefreshPeriodMin", 0); //found this property by looking at the plaintext of the RTSSHooks.dll ... It didn't appear to change the value in RTSS... I hope I didn't break something lol
    //SetProfileProperty("", "CoordinateSpace", 1); //IDK what these do, but I thought they would
    //SetProfileProperty("", "CoordinateSpace", 0);
    //DWORD coordinateSpace = CRTSSClient::GetProfileProperty("", "CoordinateSpace");
    //CGroupedString strOSDBuilder(dwMaxTextSize - 1); //I have no freaking clue what this CGroupedString class does, so I'm kind of scared to get rid of it.
    //m_SysLatStatsClient.GetOSDText(strOSDBuilder, bFormatTagsSupported, bObjTagsSupported);   // get OSD text
*/
                            
HBRUSH CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    return m_brush;
}

//This is a duplicate function that was only used for testing, but I think it needs to be moved here so I left it for now...




void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::CheckUpdate() {
    const char* APItarget = "/api/updateSysLat";
    Json::Value versionNumber;
    versionNumber["version"] = VER_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR;
    versionNumber["versionMajor"] = VERSION_MAJOR;
    versionNumber["versionMinor"] = VERSION_MINOR;

    DEBUG_PRINT(VER_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR)

    boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body> uploadStatus;
    if (m_bTestUploadMode) {
        uploadStatus = upload_data(versionNumber, APItarget);
    }
    else {
        uploadStatus = upload_data_secure(versionNumber, APItarget);
    }

    DEBUG_PRINT("uploadStatus.body(): " + uploadStatus.body())
    int userUpdateChoice = 0;

    if (uploadStatus.result_int() == 302) {
        userUpdateChoice = ::MessageBox(NULL, "Click ok to download the newest version of SysLat or cancel to continue", "Update Available", MB_OKCANCEL);
    }

    if (userUpdateChoice == 1) {
        string newFilePath = pathToSysLat;
        SL::RemoveFileNameFromPath(newFilePath);
        newFilePath += "\SysLat.exe";
        URLDownloadToFile(NULL, uploadStatus.body().c_str(), newFilePath.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        //if download completed properly...
        ::MessageBox(NULL, ("Download complete. Please close this window and start the new version of SysLat at: " + newFilePath).c_str(), "Update Complete", MB_OK);
        //else {
            //download failed
        //}
    }   
}

// if option is no, check to see if it exists and delete it if it does(probably can't use "RegOpenKeyEx" for this)
// if option is yes open and/or create the key
    //if it already exists, delete its value? or delete the entire thing itself?
    //then (re)create it

void CSysLat_SoftwareDlg::SetSURegValue(string regValue) {

    string regSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");//SysLat
    string regValueName = "SysLat";
    DEBUG_PRINT(regValue)
        
    try
    {
        size_t bufferSize = 0xFFF; // If too small, will be resized down below.
        auto cbData = static_cast<DWORD>(regValue.size() * sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));//leaving off "bufferSize * sizeof(char)" caused Windows defender to think SysLat was a trojan... Maybe? IDK, the problem just went away all of a sudden.
        HKEY hKey;
        DWORD position;
        
        auto rc = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regSubKey.c_str(), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, &position);
        if ((position == REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY || position == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY) && rc == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            if (position == REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY) {
                DEBUG_PRINT("Key already exists & has been opened.")
            }
            else if (position == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY) {
                DEBUG_PRINT("Created new key.")
            }

            auto rc = RegSetValueEx(hKey, regValueName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)regValue.data(), cbData);
            if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS){
                throw std::runtime_error("Windows system error code: " + to_string(rc));
            }
        }
        else if(rc != ERROR_SUCCESS){
            DEBUG_PRINT("Error setting key.\n")
        }
        else {
            DEBUG_PRINT("UNKNOWN ERROR: Key does not exist, and a new key was not created.")
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT(e.what())
    }
}


//DEBUG_PRINT("BYTE*: " + to_string(sizeof(BYTE*)));
//DEBUG_PRINT("BYTE: " + to_string(sizeof(BYTE)));
//DEBUG_PRINT("char*: " + to_string(sizeof(char*)));
//DEBUG_PRINT("char: " + to_string(sizeof(char)));
//ASSERT(sizeof(BYTE*) == sizeof(char));

//I never used this function, but it seemed like it could be really nice in the future...
//inline std::wstring convert(const std::string& as)
//{
//  wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[as.size() * 2 + 2];
//  swprintf(buf, L"%S", as.c_str());
//  std::wstring rval = buf;
//  delete[] buf;
//  return rval;
//}
```

Full files if interested:
https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLat_SoftwareDlg.h
https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software/blob/master/SysLat_SoftwareDlg.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General Observations

This section is about the program as a whole and not the specific files you mentioned in the question.

You are using publicly available libraries rather than writing all of the solution yourself, this is very good.

You are using GitHub for source control and that is also very good. Since you are using GitHub for source control you should remove all commented out code since you can go back to earlier versions of the code using git. Commented out code generally indicates that the code is not production ready and also not ready for code review.

This answer also applies to your 3 other questions [SysLat Cleanup #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256046/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-1), [SysLat Cleanup #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256063/turning-a-data-class-with-too-much-functionality-into-a-pod-syslat-cleanup-2) and [SysLat Cleanup #3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256149/cleaning-up-usb-implementation-use-syslat-cleanup-3).

### SOLID Object Oriented Programming

I would suggestion that you learn about [SOLID Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), especially the Single Responsibility Principle. Most of the classes and class methods in the program are too complex (do too much). This makes the program and each of the classes in the program harder to read, write, debug, and maintain. A well designed class or method does only one thing but does it well. Well designed classes or methods can be used as building blocks for more complex classes and allow reuse in other programs or solutions.

SOLID is 5 object oriented design principles. [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) is a mnemonic acronym for five design principles intended to  make software designs more understandable, flexible and maintainable. This will help you design your objects and classes better.

1. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) - A class should only have a single responsibility, that is, only changes to one part of the software's specification should be able to affect the specification of the class.
2. The [Open–closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) - states software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification.
3. The [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.
4. The [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) - states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.
5. The [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) - is a specific form of decoupling software modules. When following this principle, the conventional dependency relationships established from high-level, policy-setting modules to low-level, dependency modules are reversed, thus rendering high-level modules independent of the low-level module implementation details.

### Use Design Patterns

The 2 design patterns that would be of the most use to this program are the [MVC (Model View Controller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern and the [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

> Model–view–controller (usually known as MVC) is a software design pattern commonly used for developing user interfaces > that divides the related program logic into three interconnected elements. This is done to separate internal
> representations of information from the ways information is presented to and accepted from the user.

Among other things, using the MVC design pattern will allow you to have portable code for the `model` portion and hopefully the `controller` portion of your software so if you want to port the program to other systems besides Windows you can with less work.

The Composite Design Pattern allows you to create a hierarchy of classes within a class building very complex objects from very simple objects that do only one thing. It also reduces the complexity of inheritance. While C++ allows for inheritance from multiple classes, many programming languages do not and composition is a way around that.

### Use Released Libraries

Rather than use the boost::beast library from GitHub, use the entire boost library from boost.org which contains both the beast library and the `asio` libraries. This will ensure that the library is debugged to the best of the developers ability and it will be stable. The link from your README.md is pointing to the development branch of the `beast` library rather than the master version which means your are using unproven/undebugged code. That may have caused some of your issues in development.

### Use Portable Variable Types

In some of the program that interacts with low level Microsoft libraries you are using Microsoft specific variable types such as `DWORD`. This will make the program harder to port to other platforms. Instead I recommend finding the definition of those types in the header files and using the base definition instead (for `DWORD` it is unsigned long). Another Microsoft type I see in use is `BOOL`, C++ has the type `bool` instead, the Microsoft type was necessary for the C programming language before the `stdbool.h` header was introduced. In some cases when you port the software you will need to have code in #ifdef Win32 for the Windows version and #else for Linux.

The later versions of C++ (C++17 and C++20) have portable code for dealing with the [file system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), it would be better to use the C++ libraries because the code is portable.

### More Portability Issues

The code uses a Microsoft defined macro, `MAX_PATH` to creat arrays of char, I would suggest creating your own constants instead and use `const` or `constexpr` to declare them rather than using macros. `#define` macros should generally be avoided in C++, they don't provide type checking, where C++ `const` and `constexpr` do.

### Headers

Rather than including all the standard headers in `StdAfx.h` only include them where you need them. By including them in `StdAfx.h` you are making `StdAfx.h` huge, which makes every one of the `.cpp` files that includes it huge. For maintenance reasons it is also better to include the headers in the `.cpp` file so that whoever is maintaining the code can find it easily (If this program does well then you may have to hire employees to maintain the code).

Rather than putting the following code into `StdAfx.h`:

```
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::map;
using std::string_view;
using std::to_string;
```

it would be better to just put `std::?????` into the code. Putting `using std::string;` into `StdAfx.h` may break other string implementations (the boost library is sometimes used to develop features that are later added to the C++ standard). If you do want to shorten `std::string` to `string` then do it on a file by file basis so someone that needs to maintain the code knows where it came from.

You may also want to define your own `map` or `string_view` at some point and may run into name collisions.

Comment: Thank you for this @pacmaninbw! I think my lack of following the SOLID method has made templating much more difficult to learn/implement.  I'll study all of this and get back to you in a couple of weeks to let you know how it went.

Comment: @Skewjo I think it rather important that you switch to the released versions of the libraries as well.